# Firebase how to get data for single page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have simply project where I learn firebase and anfularfire.

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','firebase']);

    myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "home.html",
            controller: "TodoCtrl"
        })
        .when("/$id", {
            templateUrl: "single.html",
            controller: "SinglePage"
        })
    });

myApp.controller('TodoCtrl', function TodoCtrl($scope, $location, $firebase) {
    var fireRef = new Firebase('https://burning-heat-LINK.firebaseio.com/users');
    $scope.todos = $firebase(fireRef).$asArray();

    $scope.newTodo = '';


    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        var newTodo = $scope.newTodo;
        if (!newTodo.length) {
            return
        }
        $scope.todos.$add({
            title: newTodo
        })
        $scope.newTodo = ''
    };


    $scope.removeTodo = function(todo){
        $scope.todos.$remove(todo);
    };

    $scope.doneEditing = function(todo){
        var title = todo.title;
        if (title) {
            $scope.todos.$save(todo);
        } else {
            $scope.removeTodo(todo);
        }
    };

});
```

I have problem how to get data for single user page. When i click to link link below i wont to go page where the data is only the single user.

```
<a ng-href="/#/{{todo.$id}}">{{todo.$id}}</a>


myApp.controller('SinglePage', function SinglePage($scope, $location, $firebase) {
    var singlePageFirebase = new Firebase('https://burning-heat-LINK.firebaseio.com/').child('users');
    $scope.singlePage = $firebase(singlePageFirebase);
    console.log("singlePage", $scope.singlePage);
});
```

Comment: You've put `.when("/$id", {`  in your router rule. Obviously $id isn't going to work here, according to [the docs for ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07). Hint: you want `:id` instead.

Comment: You have rigth :) but when a go to single page how to get data only for this page like this:

`{
"completed":true,
"login":"Kwiatek",
"name":"Robert",
"$id":"-KE_G0X5jfO6CTtKDmz7",
"$priority":null
}`

not all data in JSON

this is the real question

`new Firebase('https://burning-heat-LINK.firebaseio.com/').child('users')`

Comment: something like that : 
`var singlePageFirebase = new Firebase('https://burning-heat-LINK.firebaseio.com/users/'+id);`